SOLVED: Compression on TIFFs - two identical images, same compression gives radically different sizes
EDIT 3: The mystery (why the tiffs differ in size) is solved, but I have found no solution to the base problem (how to create the smaller tiffs).
The mystery was how the Java program handles the compression method for CCITT T.6, aka "Fax 4" aka "Group 4". Without knowing the exact details, this method clips down the image into "strips". While the original, small image, had the entire image to be one strip, and thus only used ONE uint32 to inform the reader of how big that strip was, and where the startbyte was, the Java program seemingly had just one pixel row per strip, and thus repeated the same information 3508 times. As each information was two uint32, that was 24K of unnecessary information. That does not account for the entire 60K difference, but it is an indication.
(For the record, GIMP saved the TIFF into strips of 128 pixel rows, thus  only needing 28 strips for the entire image.)
Original question:
Running the risk of this being a stupid question, I ran into a strange mystery with TIFF image files that I hope that some compression guru can explain.
The mystery is this: Two seemingly in all aspects identical TIFF images, yet one takes up 9K space, and the other 63K.
(Unfortunately, I cannot share the image files, due to secrecy issues. I also have no possibility to create "dummy" files at this point. I am asking in the hope that there is a general answer to this mystery.)
The background is that two separate programs in our company have each created TIFF-images of what was originally a page in a PDF. Both images have the same size (2480 x 3507), the same DPI (300) and the same compression method: CCITT T.6, when you right-click and ask for Properties.
Yet one is 9K big, and the other is 63K. Another example of a slightly more complicated image, the smaller is 24K and the other file is 93K. Showing exactly the same clear black-and-white drawing image.  If you zoom in, they are not pixel-identical, as one is a tiff of the PDF with added margin, and the other is without margins. But neither of them is dithered. It's just clear, strokes, with smooth outlines, no single pixels here and there. Nothing that would explain why on earth one would take up 4 times as much space.
I assume that there is something here that I simply do not know. I thought CCITT T.6 was a compression method. Isn't it? Is CCITT T.6 just some standard, that can be implemented in different ways, resulting in completely different file sizes?
EDIT 1: I tried to crop out parts of the images that I could share, but none of the image editors I found could "only" crop - Paint et al saved tiffs in LZW without any option, and while GIMP allowed me to export any opened images to T.6 tiffs, I lost the original metadata in the process. For the record, GIMP exported both the 5K tiff and the 65K tiff into a 6K tiff. From the information in GIMP, I could not discern what the difference between the two images were.
EDIT 2: I used the exiftool to analyze the images, as per Mark Setchell's advice below. And while this didn't solve the base problem (we wanted to be able to make small images), they still did shed light over what the difference was.
This is the output from exiftool -v -v -v for the smaller image:
  ExifToolVersion = 13.02
  FileName = A1_15_kopia.tiff
  Directory = c:/temp/tiffmysteriet
  FileSize = 5088
  FileModifyDate = 1731397794.09064
  FileAccessDate = 1731403112.93248
  FileCreateDate = 1731397793.84405
  FilePermissions = 33206
  FileType = TIFF
  FileTypeExtension = TIF
  MIMEType = image/tiff
  ExifByteOrder = II
  + [IFD0 directory with 20 entries]
  | 0)  SubfileType = 2
  |     - Tag 0x00fe (4 bytes, int32u[1]):
  |         0012: 02 00 00 00                                     [....]
  | 1)  ImageWidth = 2480
  |     - Tag 0x0100 (4 bytes, int32u[1]):
  |         001e: b0 09 00 00                                     [....]
  | 2)  ImageHeight = 3508
  |     - Tag 0x0101 (4 bytes, int32u[1]):
  |         002a: b4 0d 00 00                                     [....]
  | 3)  BitsPerSample = 1
  |     - Tag 0x0102 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         0036: 01 00                                           [..]
  | 4)  Compression = 4
  |     - Tag 0x0103 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         0042: 04 00                                           [..]
  | 5)  PhotometricInterpretation = 0
  |     - Tag 0x0106 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         004e: 00 00                                           [..]
  | 6)  FillOrder = 1
  |     - Tag 0x010a (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         005a: 01 00                                           [..]
  | 7)  StripOffsets = 338
  |     - Tag 0x0111 (4 bytes, int32u[1]):
  |         0066: 52 01 00 00                                     [R...]
  | 8)  Orientation = 1
  |     - Tag 0x0112 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         0072: 01 00                                           [..]
  | 9)  SamplesPerPixel = 1
  |     - Tag 0x0115 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         007e: 01 00                                           [..]
  | 10) RowsPerStrip = 3508
  |     - Tag 0x0116 (4 bytes, int32u[1]):
  |         008a: b4 0d 00 00                                     [....]
  | 11) StripByteCounts = 4750
  |     - Tag 0x0117 (4 bytes, int32u[1]):
  |         0096: 8e 12 00 00                                     [....]
  | 12) XResolution = 300 (300/1)
  |     - Tag 0x011a (8 bytes, rational64u[1]):
  |         00fe: 2c 01 00 00 01 00 00 00                         [,.......]
  | 13) YResolution = 300 (300/1)
  |     - Tag 0x011b (8 bytes, rational64u[1]):
  |         0106: 2c 01 00 00 01 00 00 00                         [,.......]
  | 14) PlanarConfiguration = 1
  |     - Tag 0x011c (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         00ba: 01 00                                           [..]
  | 15) T6Options = 0
  |     - Tag 0x0125 (4 bytes, int32u[1]):
  |         00c6: 00 00 00 00                                     [....]
  | 16) ResolutionUnit = 2
  |     - Tag 0x0128 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         00d2: 02 00                                           [..]
  | 17) PageNumber = 0 0
  |     - Tag 0x0129 (4 bytes, int16u[2]):
  |         00de: 00 00 00 00                                     [....]
  | 18) Software = GPL Ghostscript 8.54
  |     - Tag 0x0131 (21 bytes, string[21]):
  |         010e: 47 50 4c 20 47 68 6f 73 74 73 63 72 69 70 74 20 [GPL Ghostscript ]
  |         011e: 38 2e 35 34 00                                  [8.54.]
  | 19) ModifyDate = 2021:11:29 09:51:35
  |     - Tag 0x0132 (20 bytes, string[20]):
  |         0136: 32 30 32 31 3a 31 31 3a 32 39 20 30 39 3a 35 31 [2021:11:29 09:51]
  |         0146: 3a 33 35 00                                     [:35.]
  PageCount = 1

And this is the output from exiftool -v -v -v for the larger image:
  ExifToolVersion = 13.02
  FileName = C2_20_kopia.tiff
  Directory = c:/temp/tiffmysteriet
  FileSize = 64905
  FileModifyDate = 1731396207.24214
  FileAccessDate = 1731401273.16017
  FileCreateDate = 1731397823.12243
  FilePermissions = 33206
  FileType = TIFF
  FileTypeExtension = TIF
  MIMEType = image/tiff
  ExifByteOrder = MM
  + [IFD0 directory with 11 entries]
  | 0)  ImageWidth = 2480
  |     - Tag 0x0100 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         0012: 09 b0                                           [..]
  | 1)  ImageHeight = 3508
  |     - Tag 0x0101 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         001e: 0d b4                                           [..]
  | 2)  Compression = 4
  |     - Tag 0x0103 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         002a: 00 04                                           [..]
  | 3)  PhotometricInterpretation = 0
  |     - Tag 0x0106 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         0036: 00 00                                           [..]
  | 4)  StripOffsets = 28228 28232 28236 28240 28244 28248 28252 28256 28260 28264 2826[snip]
  |     - Tag 0x0111 (14032 bytes, int32u[3508]):
  |         0094: 00 00 6e 44 00 00 6e 48 00 00 6e 4c 00 00 6e 50 [..nD..nH..nL..nP]
  |         00a4: 00 00 6e 54 00 00 6e 58 00 00 6e 5c 00 00 6e 60 [..nT..nX..n\..n`]
  |         00b4: 00 00 6e 64 00 00 6e 68 00 00 6e 6c 00 00 6e 70 [..nd..nh..nl..np]
  |         00c4: 00 00 6e 74 00 00 6e 78 00 00 6e 7c 00 00 6e 80 [..nt..nx..n|..n.]
  |         00d4: 00 00 6e 84 00 00 6e 88 00 00 6e 8c 00 00 6e 90 [..n...n...n...n.]
  |         [snip 13952 bytes]
  | 5)  SamplesPerPixel = 1
  |     - Tag 0x0115 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         004e: 00 01                                           [..]
  | 6)  RowsPerStrip = 1
  |     - Tag 0x0116 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         005a: 00 01                                           [..]
  | 7)  StripByteCounts = 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4[snip]
  |     - Tag 0x0117 (14032 bytes, int32u[3508]):
  |         3764: 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 [................]
  |         3774: 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 [................]
  |         3784: 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 [................]
  |         3794: 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 [................]
  |         37a4: 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 [................]
  |         [snip 13952 bytes]
  | 8)  XResolution = 300 (300/1)
  |     - Tag 0x011a (8 bytes, rational64u[1]):
  |         6e34: 00 00 01 2c 00 00 00 01                         [...,....]
  | 9)  YResolution = 300 (300/1)
  |     - Tag 0x011b (8 bytes, rational64u[1]):
  |         6e3c: 00 00 01 2c 00 00 00 01                         [...,....]
  | 10) ResolutionUnit = 2
  |     - Tag 0x0128 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |         008a: 00 02                                           [..]


It appears to be some variant of non-adaptive (fixed-table) Huffman coding. So nothing they can do wrong there while still following the standard. Single-pixel data can make it sad. Are your differences some one-pixel borders?

Install thepoppler package and run pdfimages command. Or run exiftool -v -v -v


KJ : Thanks, I found that thread too, but I didn't gain much from it.
This mystery leads me to believe that, while both images share the CCITT T.6 compression method, there are more or less effective ways to implement that method.

The small image was created by GPL Ghostscript 8.54, and the larger version was created by using the Java built-in standard for saving TIFFs.
I tried to crop out unidentifiable parts of the images in order to share without breaking secrecy, but all simple image softwares I found saved TIFFs with LZW compression. I'll post again if I find a solution.


Mark Setchell: Thanks. I've added the information to the original question. The exiftool did indeed show differences, but I am not knowledgeable enough to decipher them.



Mark Setchell: I finally understand the exiftool's output. Your solution identified the problem, but didn't solve it. All that I know now is that Java's built-in TIFF compressor for T.6 is completely stupid. I have updated the question to mark it solved.

